# Display the user avatar in  a user panel

Tags: blocks, users, media

Is there an alternative to make the login box that turns into the default user panel (My Account, Administer etc.) display the user's profile picture above the username?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually two separate blocks, *User login* that is displayed only to anonymous users and *Navigation* that only gets displayed once user has logged in. You are interested in modifying the latter one.

Unfortunately, there's no `hook_block_alter()` around that you could use to modify the block from a custom module. However, you can do so from within your theme just before the block gets displayed.

Just pop the following function into YOURTHEME's `template.php` and it should work. Please, note, this adds the user picture to the top of the block content, just *below* the user name.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  $block =& $vars['block'];
  if ($block->module == 'user' && $block->delta == 1) {
    // Navigation block.
    $block->content = theme('user_picture', $vars['user']) . $block->content;
  }
}
```

If you want it above the username, just replace `$block->content` with `$block->subject`.

Or, even better, just create another block, place it above the *Navigation*, make it only visible specifically to `authenticated user` role, set the *Body title* to `<none>`, and *Block body* to:

```
<?php
global $user;    
print theme('user_picture', $user);
?>
```

Make sure to enable the *PHP filter* module first and use *PHP code* filter for the *Block body* input.

Comment: This is perfect thanks mate! Just one little issue, it's outputting two of them. I'll post a fix to this specific case soon if I find it.

Comment: Also, not sure if this shows a default picture if the user has no picture selected.

Comment: That should be easy to figure out. :-)

Comment: I have the default set, and it shows in their profiles, but not on the side in the block. So I think it believes if no picture is set, it is NULL, so it won't render it in PHP (nothing in the code to show it is printing it).

As for the double picture, still working on that :)

Comment: I tested it and seems to work okay here. The theme('user_picture') function takes care of everything. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Hey mate, just catching you up - I made the block with the PHP code rather than hardcoding it into the theme and it worked perfectly. Thankyou a million times over, you're a legend!

Answer (score 3):

You could use Views that would give you a more flexible option, because you can add any fields from the user using the Views UI. You would need to:

1. Create a View that display Users
2. Add a contextual filter for the Uid.
3. Set the configurations of contextual filter's 'When the filter value is NOT in the URL' options to 'Provide default argument - User ID from logged in user'.
4. Add the fields you need, in your case User Picture and Name.
5. Add a block display and display the block wherever you want/

Comment: The problem with creating a view is that each page has to call the view which can get expensive.

Comment: You can always use something like: http://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache or Boost, Varnish, etc. But I know what you mean, it is more expensive, but a lot more flexible too and relatively easier for a beginner.

Comment: @ipwa : Just found this helpful post, thank you ! Can you be more specific when you say :
*Add a contextual filter for the Uid.* ? Can't find it. Thank you.

Comment: It's in the advanced sections of views, have a look at: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views or http://dev.nodeone.se/node/772